# Div element undefined for addEventListener inside loop

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

Here is the HTML and JS code:

```js
let sides = document.getElementsByClassName("sides");

for (var i=0;i<sides.length;i++){
    console.log(sides[i].innerHTML);  // top left 
    sides[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(sides[i]);  //Undefined
    })
}
```

```html
<div class="sides">top</div>
<div class="sides">left</div>
```

When I `console.log(sides[i])` I'm getting the div elements but when I'm adding the `addEventListener` it's showing `undefined`.

Please someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also console.log `e.target`

```
<div class="sides">Top</div>
<div class="sides">Left</div>

<script>
    let sides = document.getElementsByClassName("sides");

    for (let i=0;i<sides.length;i++){
        console.log(sides[i].innerHTML);  // top left 
        sides[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            console.log(e.target);
        })
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `sides[i]` to `this` so that it can refer to the clicked element itself. The reason your solution doesn't work is because your variable `i` gets incremented to 2 after the last iteration because of `i++`. So when the event listener is triggered, `sides[i]` is now `sides[2]`. Another way is to instantiate the `i` using `let` as `let i = 0`, then you can access `sides[i]`

```html
<div class="sides">top</div>
<div class="sides">left</div>


<script>
    let sides = document.getElementsByClassName("sides");

    for (let i=0;i<sides.length;i++){
        console.log(sides[i].innerHTML);  // top left 
        sides[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            console.log(this);
            console.log(sides[i])
        })
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also assign an `onclick()` method to the element like below, but inside of the function you would still refer to the element with `this` so that `console.log()` knows which element's `innerHTML` you are trying to print. In this case it's own.

```js
let sides = document.getElementsByClassName("sides");

for (var i=0; i<sides.length; i++) {
    console.log(sides[i].innerHTML);  // top left 
    sides[i].onclick = function() {
        console.log(this.innerHTML);  // Not undefined
    };
}
```

```html
<div class="sides">top</div>
<div class="sides">left</div>
```

Or you could also create a function to handle the click event, in which case you would again use `this` to refer to the clicked element:

```js
function someFunc() {
  console.log(this.innerHTML);  // Not undefined
}

let sides = document.getElementsByClassName("sides");

for (var i=0; i<sides.length; i++) {
    console.log(sides[i].innerHTML);  // top left 
    sides[i].addEventListener("click", someFunc);
}
```

```html
<div class="sides">top</div>
<div class="sides">left</div>
```